# A sudden swap in double-single bonds in a 3D Tour video around a benzene molecule

Tags: tour3dvideo, moleculeplot3d

```
g = MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["benzene"], SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image: Benzene molecule]

I am trying to realise a 30 seconds video of a tour around a benzene molecule from different of point views. The position of the camera is as follow.

```
dur = 30;
position[t_] := {10  Sin[(t/dur)  2  Pi] Cos[8 (t/dur)  2  Pi], 
  10  Sin[(t/dur)  2  Pi] Sin[8 (t/dur)  2  Pi], 
  10  Cos[(t/dur)  2  Pi]}
Show[g, ParametricPlot3D[position[t], {t, 0, dur}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Trajectory of the tour]

The video is generate with the function "Tour3DVideo" with the code:

```
Tour3DVideo[g, position, FrameRate -> 25, DefaultDuration -> dur]
```

In the generate video, at 15 seconds, there is a suddend exchange between the double and single bonds of the benzene ring. How can avoid this exchange?

Comment: You don't need to use `Show`, you could do it entirely like this `Animate[
 With[{p = position[t]},
  MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["benzene"], SphericalRegion -> True, 
   ViewPoint -> p, ViewVector -> -p, ViewProjection -> "Perspective"]
  ] , {t, 0, dur}]`

Comment: `position` is too complicated for this tour. There are small cycles that incompatible with frame rate. Try for example  `position[t_] := {10   Sin[(t/dur)   2   Pi]  Cos[2 (t/dur)   2   Pi], 10   Sin[(t/dur)   2   Pi]  Sin[2  (t/dur)   2   Pi], 10   Cos[(t/dur)   2   Pi]}`